# Cannot import the attribute from "abc.py" in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, attributes, abc

I have `hello()` in `test/abc.py` as shown below:

```py
# "test/abc.py"

def hello():
    return "Hello"
```

Then, I import and call `hello()` from `abc.py` in `test/main.py` as shown below:

```py
# "test/main.py"

from abc import hello

print(hello())
```

But, I got the error below:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'hello' from 'abc'

So, I import `abc.py` and call `abc.hello()` in `test/main.py` as shown below:

```py
# "test/main.py"

import abc

print(abc.hello())
```

But, I got another error below:

> AttributeError: module 'abc' has no attribute 'hello'

Actually, I can import `abc.py` without error as shown below:

```py
import abc

# print(abc.hello())
```

So, how can I import and call `hello()` from `abc.py`?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you import the built-in module [abc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#module-abc) which means **Abstract Base Classes** to create abstract classes so don't create the file with the name `abc.py`. *You can see all built-in modules in [Python Module Index](https://docs.python.org/3/py-modindex.html) which you cannot use as file names.

So, you should change `abc.py` to other name such as `greeting.py` as shown below:

```py
# "test/greeting.py"

def hello():
    return "Hello"
```

Then, both work without error as shown below:

```py
# "test/main.py"

from greeting import hello

print(hello()) # Hello
```

```py
# "test/main.py"

import greeting

print(greeting.hello()) # Hello
```

In addition, importing `def.py` below gets `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` error because `def` is a reserved word to define functions. *You can see all reserved words in [2.3.1 Keywords](https://docs.python.org/2.5/ref/keywords.html) and don't use `abcdef`'s `abc` and `def` as file names:

```py
import def # Error
```

Answer (score 0):

Your **problem** here is the **file name** for "abc.py." This is already a file within the included core libraries that ships with python.

We can see from [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html) that when you import the Abstract Base Classes library, your code matches the import statement, thus **causing an issue**.

```
# Change "abc.py" to "something.py" or anything that won't conflict with core libs

# "test/something.py"

def hello():
    return "Hello"
```

Here are some ways to import this function:

```
# "test/main.py"

from something.py import hello     # will import only that function
from something.py import *         # will import all functions from file



# If you had multiple functions in the file, you can use only one line 
# without importing all other functions by using commas:

from something.py import hello, goodbye, seeYaLater



# THIS IS A TRICKY ONE:

import something

# When you import the file this way, you are going to need to
# reference the function with `something.hello()` which is a 
# real pain in the butt. Unless you have conflicting function 
# names across different files, I would avoid this one.


print(hello())
```

If you are ever unsure whether a file name is already taken by python, a modern code IDE such as Visual Studio Code has an extension called Pylance that will notify you of any collisions.

(Take a look at **Semantic Highlighting** and **Automatic Imports** from [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/have-you-tried-pylance-for-vs-code-if-not-heres-why-you-should-a8a7b5adc5f2))

Hope this helps!